# How to keep PyGTK AppIndicator menu open after click?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygtk, python-3.6, appindicator

I was trying to toy around with the `pygtk` module to make an app indicator in my top bar in Ubuntu 17.10.

With a little research, I have successfully made a menu where you can pause the main thread (which just prints "Update" to the console currently.)

Now I've stumbled across a problem and couldn't find an answer.

I plan to make a radio streamer for the top bar and the menu closing on every click would be very undesirable for navigation when searching.

How can I make the menu stay open when clicking an item?

Here is my code:

```
import os
import signal
import time
from threading import Thread

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("AppIndicator3", "0.1")

from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import GObject as gobject


class Indicator:

    def __init__(self, name=None, icon=None):

        self.path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

        if name is None:
            self.name = "MyApp"
        else:
            self.name = name

        if icon is None:
            self.icon = gtk.STOCK_INFO
        else:
            self.icon = icon

        self.indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(
            self.name, self.icon,
            appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES
            )

        self.indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

        self.running = True
        self.paused = False

        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update)
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = gtk.Menu()

        pause_entry = gtk.MenuItem("Pause")
        pause_entry.connect("activate", self.pause)
        menu.append(pause_entry)

        quit_entry = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
        quit_entry.connect("activate", self.quit)
        menu.append(quit_entry)

        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def update(self):
        while self.running:
            time.sleep(1)
            if not self.paused:
                print("Update", flush=True)

    def start(self):
        gobject.threads_init()
        gtk.main()

    def pause(self, menu):
        self.paused = not self.paused
        text = "Resume" if self.paused else "Pause"
        for widget in menu.get_children():
            print(widget.get_text())
            widget.set_text(text)

    def quit(self, menu=None):
        self.running = False
        gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    indicator = Indicator()
    indicator.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can make the menu stay open when clicking on an item.

This was an intentional design [decision](https://bugs.launchpad.net/screenlets/+bug/522152) taken by the AppIndicator developers in order to ensure that the indicator would function in a consistent and uniform way and that no custom actions(e.g. right-click, mouseover etc) would be possible to be applied on by end users.

I have created an [appindicator](https://github.com/0dysseas/news-indicator) that displays news in real time and when I researched the related pygtk/appindicator API reference material; the only allowed supported menu action that I came across was that of scrolling.

With regards to your radio streamer project I suggest have the menu as the main focal point of your application and have the menu items appropriately bidden to pygtk windows. Then use [callbacks and signals](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtktutorial/sec-theoryofsignalsandcallbacks.html) to perform your necessary actions. This is the approach I undertook in my little project too and turned out pretty nicely.

Comment: Hi @kingJulian. Thanks for the answer. I had suspiscion that this was a design choice as I couldn't find way to keep the menu open. I've used `gtk.Window` before, I was just hoping there was maybe a way, or at least a workaround possibly, to keep the menu open when clicking. Thanks for your input!